# How to get the ng-model value inside a directive from a nested element?

Tags: angularjs

How do I get the value of a ngModel inside the link-function of a nested HTML-element, i.e.:

```
<div myattr>
 <label>Title</label>
 <input type="text" ng-model="need.value.of.this">
</div>
```

'`myattr`' has to remain inside the top div-element.

So, what's the way to get the value of `'need.value.of.this`' inside the link function? Normally I would use '`required: ngModel`'  and then use the ngModelCtrl with `$viewValue`. Is there a way to get the `ngModelCtrl` of input inside the link function?

```
app.directive('myattr', [
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) { 
            // need ng-model value from input
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you can register the ng-model on myattr, in the similar way ng-model registers itself to ng-form element

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('myattr', [
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
           ngModel: '=',
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) { 
            // need ng-model value from input
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `scope` to get the ngModel value from your `DOM` to access it in your `link` function

Answer (score 0):

You can add watcher to your scope

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) { 
   $scope.$watch('need.value.of.this', function(newValue) {
      // do something with new value
   });
}
```

Comment: Hi, my ng-model can be different... putting a watcher on "need.value.of.this" is too specific for me, with ngModel.$viewValue I solved this problem... but now I have nested elements and ngModel is undefined)... any solution?